# GraphQL Type Coercion

Tags: graphql, coercion

I am currently updating some documentation we have in relation to our unit testing for GraphQL, I have come across this sentence:

"GraphQL does some type coercion behind the scenes. We need to mimic this type coercion in our mock data."

"One example is it will convert [bits](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bit) to booleans. When adding mock data from B2 that includes bits, these should be changed to booleans in the mock data files, so that the unit tests will run as expected."

Unfortunately the person who originally wrote this has left our business,  I understand that there is some type coercion undertaken by GraphQL but I am keen to know why this is done? Especially during the result coercion. Does anybody have any ideas what this means?

Comment: I may be missing some context here, but those comments don't really make sense to me. The whole point of result coercion is that the resolver can return one or more types that are native to the language you're working with and these are coerced into a GraphQL-specific type. If your data source normally returns a bit type and GraphQL is able to correctly coerce this into a Boolean, it's unclear why your mock data should be something else.

Answer (score 2):

From the [spec](https://graphql.github.io/graphql-spec/June2018/#sec-Scalars):

> A GraphQL server, when preparing a field of a given scalar type, must uphold the contract the scalar type describes, either by coercing the value or producing a field error if a value cannot be coerced or if coercion may result in data loss.
>
> A GraphQL service may decide to allow coercing different internal types to the expected return type. For example when coercing a field of type Int a boolean true value may produce 1 or a string value "123" may be parsed as base‐10 123. However if internal type coercion cannot be reasonably performed without losing information, then it must raise a field error.
>
> Since this coercion behavior is not observable to clients of the GraphQL server, the precise rules of coercion are left to the implementation. The only requirement is that the server must yield values which adhere to the expected Scalar type.

Additional rules specific to the five built-in scalars can be found can be found in their respective sections. How any other scalars behave in this regard is left up to the individual service.

Comment: Thanks for your response it seems the documentation that was given to me was not clear to begin with.